# Project Euler program 10 not giving write answer in my program

Tags: java

I just started doing project Euler’s problems, I’m on 10th problem. Here it is: The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17. Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

My code is:

```java
public class SummationOfPrimes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum = 2;
        for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++) {
            if (primeOrNot(i)) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    static Boolean primeOrNot(long input) {
        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(input); i++) {
            if (input % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I’m getting wrong answer: `143042032118`.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking for answers for project euler....it defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Mohammed S, OP gave us code that demonstrated sufficient research into the problem to warrant posting and answering. The bug (if I'm correct) is a subtle one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, by the way, always helpful to have some idea as to how far out your solution is.

If the answer is close (and I assume it is), then I focus immediately on your primality test which is incorrect; you are not testing prime square numbers like 4, 9, ..., 49 correctly; you need to go up to *and including* the square root (rounding down to integral is permissible).

Write

```
for (int i = 2; i<= Math.sqrt(input); ++i){
```

instead.

Also there is a problem with the starting loop value and the initial value of the sum (acknowledge Jean-Baptiste Yunès): either write `long sum = 0;` or `for (int i = 3...`) in place of what you currently have.

Answer (score 2):

Two programming errors : first, you start with `i=2` but your sum is already `sum=2`, change it to `sum=0` or start at `i=3`; second, you don't test up to the square root.

Comment: Yep, after getting reply from 
Bathsheba , i corrected those errors , thanks for your reply.. :D

Comment: +1 as that was an error I didn't spot and therefore part of the accepted answer